# SelectOneMenu throwing a database exception

Tags: jsf-2.2

In my application, the user must create a list of employees and while doing that to specify for which service the employee work , i used a oneSelectMenu but when testing it it throws a database exception for trying to insert values in the service table(which is not right because i am trying to save the values in the employees table)
Here is my employee ManagedBean code

```
@ManagedBean(name="persMb")
@SessionScoped
public class PersonnelMb {
private List<ServiceInterne> serviceInternesList;
private List<Personnel> personnelsList;

private DataModel personnels;
private Integer idPers;
private ServiceInterne selectedService;
private Personnel newPersonnel = new Personnel();
private Personnel editPersonnel;
private ServiceInterneDao sDao = new ServiceInterneDao();
private PersonnelDao pDao = new PersonnelDao();

public String create() {
System.out.println("selected Service "+selectedService);
    newPersonnel.setServiceInterne(selectedService);
    pDao.ajouter(newPersonnel);
    newPersonnel = new Personnel();
    personnels.setWrappedData(pDao.selectAll());
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Ajout effectué avec succés");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    return "list";
}
```

And this is the jsf page Code

```
                            <p:column>
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{persMb.selectedService}"
                                    converter="ServiceInterneConverter">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{servInterMb.serviceInternesList}"
                                        var="s" itemLabel="#{s.libelle}" itemValue="#{s}">
                                    </f:selectItems>
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
```

And this is the stack trace of the error

```
                        2014-03-06T14:34:50.556+0100|Infos: [EL Warning]: 2014-03-06                14:34:50.555--UnitOfWork(1946319022)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
                 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: violation de contrainte unique (ELSA.SYS_C008545)
                 Error Code: 1
               Call: INSERT INTO Service_Interne (IDSERVICEINTER, LIBELLE, MISSION) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
          Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.oratech.model.ServiceInterne@2140b3d2)
                2014-03-06T14:34:50.558+0100|Avertissement: #{persMb.create}: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
       Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: violation de contrainte unique (ELSA.SYS_C008545)
          Error Code: 1
          Call: INSERT INTO Service_Interne (IDSERVICEINTER, LIBELLE, MISSION) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
       Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.oratech.model.ServiceInterne@2140b3d2)
            javax.faces.FacesException: #{persMb.create}: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
         Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: violation de contrainte unique (ELSA.SYS_C008545)
           Error Code: 1
     Call: INSERT INTO Service_Interne (IDSERVICEINTER, LIBELLE, MISSION) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
     Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.oratech.model.ServiceInterne@2140b3d2)
at                 com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
```

My RDBMS is Oracle 10g xe and my IDE is eclipse Kepler

Comment: Please remove all unrelated code, there's too much noise.
As for the error, it's not related to jsf but to your persistence model. I see you are using jpa (eclipselink). you'll have to show the Dao and the entities. how are you injecting the dao in the managed bean?

Comment: I did solve the problem.In the association @ManyToOne between the Employee and the service I did put cascade=CascadeType.All and due to that each time i create an employee it tries also to create a service and By removing it everything worked Fine